How do I display the IShellView for Windows Control Panel items?
I would like to show the IShellView for a Windows Control Panel IShellFolder item in a .NET Form. It works for regular folders, but I can't get it to work for Control Panel items.
This is how I do it:
Dim ww As System.Windows.Forms.Form = New System.Windows.Forms.Form()
ww.Show()
Dim ptr As IntPtr, shellFolder As IShellFolder, shellView As IShellView
Dim h As HRESULT
shellFolder = CType(e.NewValue, Folder).ShellFolder
Try
    h = shellFolder.CreateViewObject(IntPtr.Zero, GetType(IShellView).GUID, ptr)
    shellView = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(ptr, GetType(IShellView))
Finally
    If Not IntPtr.Zero.Equals(ptr) Then
        Marshal.Release(ptr)
    End If
End Try
Dim sb As ShellBrowser = New ShellBrowser(ww.Handle)
Dim fs As FOLDERSETTINGS
fs.fFlags = 0
fs.ViewMode = -1
Dim r As WIN32RECT = New WIN32RECT()
r.Top = 20 : r.Left = 20 : r.Right = 500 : r.Bottom = 500
shellView.CreateViewWindow(Nothing, fs, sb, r, ww.Handle)
shellView.UIActivate(1)

For a regular folder, this gives me a form with the details IShellView for the folder and it shows its items.
For a Control Panel folder however, it shows me an empty details view with only one column "Name", whereas I would expect it to show the custom Control Panel view for the item:

How can I make it show the control panel (for example for "::{8E908FC9-BECC-40F6-915B-F4CA0E70D03D}" (Network and Sharing Center)?
Edit: I've tried showing these Control Panel items in an ExplorerBrowser instance (71f96385-ddd6-48d3-a0c1-ae06e8b055fb), and I get the same result.

IShellView can only display the classic cpl icon list, how to display the fancy Control Panel pages is undocumented...

The following may be of interest: Executing Control Panel Items and Canonical Names of Control Panel Items
